# Sum attributes of feature that occurs multiple times within a layer

Tags: spatial-join, statistics, arcgis-10.6

I am trying to add up the total contributing drainage area of multiple stormwater BMP's that are located on the same parcel for a layer that contains tens of thousands of parcels. I performed a one-to-many spatial join to join the BMP points to the parcel polygon layer. Now I have a layer that contains multiple polygons for each parcel, one for each BMP present on that parcel. I would like to add together the drainage area attribute from the BMP layer for each parcel, so that I have a layer that lists each parcel only one time, but has the sum of all the drainage areas as an attribute.

Comment: I would try the Dissolve command with your Parcels. Dissolve has Statistic options like Sum, Min, Max.etc. Summary Statistics is a similar tool, has no Geometry input.

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution using the summary statistics tool using the drainage area as the statistic field and the JOIN_FID as the case field. After I came back here and saw this comment, I tried using the dissolve tool, dissolving on the JOIN_FID and taking the sum of the drainage area field. Both seemed to result in an acceptable product. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please add your solution as an answer if you solved your problem. It could be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution using the summary statistics tool using the drainage area as the statistic field and the JOIN_FID as the case field. After I came back here and saw this comment, I tried using the dissolve tool, dissolving on the JOIN_FID and taking the sum of the drainage area field. Both seemed to result in an acceptable product.